# Have margin between my cells

Tags: html, css

i have table with several cells, i want to have space between my cell `<td>`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P2GZX/63/)

```
.line {
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

.textRotation {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(n+4) th
{
    padding-left:3px;
}

.border
{
    border: 1px solid black; /* crée une bordure de 1 px noir */
}
```

I would get the same results
[image]

I update my code with the @jmore009's solution but i have a new pb

i have space in my continious line

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little change based on your fiddle, wrapped the rotation text in a `<span>`:

BEFORE

```
<th class="textRotation head"  id="go" rowspan="8">Aller</th>
<style>
.textRotation {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

AFTER

```
<th class="textRotation head"  id="go" rowspan="8"><span>Aller</span></th>
<style>
.textRotation {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.textRotation span {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    display: inline-block;   
}
</style>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2GZX/70/)

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
table{
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px; //change to what you want
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2GZX/68/)